# Запуск консольного приложения ASP.net Core на Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

Доброго времени суток подскажите как запустить консольное приложение net.Core на VPS c OS Linux.

Я создал консольное приложение net.Core, скопировал все файлы на VPS

подключаюсь через клиент по SSH к VPS (выходит командная строка) там ввожу команду:

`dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll`

Все запускается, Ура! Но как только я закрываю клиент, то и приложение не работает... а мне надо чтоб оно работало там 24/7, вот собственно вопрос как правильно запустить приложение на VPS?

Comment: То есть вам нужно запустить приложение как демон.

Comment: screen. И еще, Linux != OS. Linux is Kernel.

Comment: https://habr.com/en/post/332920/

Answer (score 4):

Создать сервис

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/<myapp>.service
```

Вписать туда примерно такую конфигурацию

```
[Unit]
Description=My application service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/<myapp>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/<myapp>/<myapp>.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=<myapp>
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Запустить сервис

```
$ sudo service <myapp> start
```

Проверить состояние сервиса

```
$ sudo systemctl | grep <myapp>
```

Источник: https://jamesnaylor.dev/Posts/Read?id=dotnet-app-on-vps